# Firebase : One of 2 apps connected to same firebase project doesn't send data to db

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Before posting this question, I searched a lot but didn't get my answer. Here's my question:

I noticed many times while working with **Firebase** android that whenever I connect **two different apps** to the same Firebase project if I install those two apps on the same device one of them is able to send/retrieve data to the database while the other is not. For example:

**1.** I recently worked on a **Uber clone** app and I accidentally installed both the rider and driver app on the same emulator device and one app was unable to send data to firebase but when I ran them both on separate devices, everything worked fine.

**2.** Now I am working on a university project **EBus** that has two modules, one for the **student** and the other for the **driver**. I am using my phone for testing today I started developing my **driver** app and installed it on my phone where the **student** app was already installed, I was unable to send data to Firebase real-time database. But, when I installed the **driver** app on a different device everything worked fine.

**My Code :**

```
public class QrScanFragment extends Fragment {
public static TextView tvName, tvRegNo, tvDept, tvRoute, tvRouteNo;
public static final int STATIC_INTEGER = 4843;

// Database
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference seatsRef;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_qr_scan, container, false);


    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    seatsRef = database.getReference(Common.SEATS_REFERENCE);

    tvName = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    tvRegNo = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_reg_no);
    tvDept = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_dept);
    tvRoute = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_route);
    tvRouteNo = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_route_no);

    // Sending data here
seatsRef.child(tvRouteNo.getText().toString()).child(Common.AVAILABLE_SEATS).setValue("15", new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError error, @NonNull DatabaseReference ref) {
            if (error != null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });


    view.findViewById(R.id.btn_qr_scan).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                   startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), QrScannerActivity.class));

        }
    });


    return view;
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}}
```

Comment: Are you using Firebase Authentication?

Comment: I haven't really faced that issue, are you sure you have used the correct credentials?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes I am using in the student app but not in the driver app.

Comment: @Dharmaraj yup I've double-checked the credentials

Comment: For further clarification, I've added the code

Comment: Did you add your SHA-1 key of your second project in firebase

Comment: @SwapnilPadaya nope, I didn't. Is it necessary?. I think SHA-1 and SHA-256 are used for phone authentications purpose only

Comment: Well try it putting it in.

Comment: @SwapnilPadaya done. Still doesn't work

Comment: Kindly check if all the apps are authenticated. If for anyone to access the data i.e reading and writing to the database and you have set it to read and write when authenticated it might be the one causing the problem.

Comment: @Kimkim For debugging. I 've done both read and write to true yet.

Comment: @SwapnilPadaya you are a savior I tried your suggestion again and added SHA -1 key to firebase, it worked. Could you please explain your answer?

Comment: There must be a reason for this failure in the Logcat. Can you please run your function again but instead of completionListener, add a successListener and a failureListener. So we can see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two unique certificates used to sign the apps you develop using Android Studio. The debug certificate is used to sign apps that are being developed and tested. The release certificate, on the other hand, is used to sign the apps when they are ready to be uploaded to the Google Play store.

These certificates take the form of SHA-1 fingerprints, Ultimately, both the release and debug fingerprints will need to be added to the Firebase project with which the Android app is associated in order to use the Google Sign-in provider.

Comment: In my case, Sign - in provider was not the problem. but somehow it solved my issue by adding the SHA-1 key of my app to the firebase console. Upvote. Thanks!!